# Evaluating a joint pdf of two random variables when input is out of bounds

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, problem-solving

So, I have a problem in which we are given a joint pdf with two random variables

$$f_{xy}(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
c(1+xy),  & 0 \le x\le4,  0\le y\le2 \\[2ex]
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

I'm confused because the problem says to find $f_{xy}(x,3)$, and 3 is out of bounds given the pdf.

For problems like this do you integrate over the bounds and use 3 as an input as shown below?

$$f_{xy}(x,3)=\int^4_0\int^2_0 c(1+x*3) \ dydx$$
$$f_{xy}(x,3)= \int^4_0c*2(3x+1) \ dx$$

$$f_{xy}(x,3)= 56c$$

Or do you evaluate the evaluate the integral over the bounds and use 0 as an input as the pdf is 0 given y = 0 as shown below

$$f_{xy}(x,3)=\int^4_0\int^2_0 c(1+x*0) \ dydx$$
$$f_{xy}(x,3)= \int^4_02c \ dx$$

$$f_{xy}(x,3)= 8c$$

If I am missing something or not understanding the concept please let me know, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you already evaluated the value for c?

Comment: @callculus yes I have already solved for c.

Comment: You want the value of $f_{XY}(x,3)$ ? I would say it is just $0$. But why you are integrating?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's far simpler than you're making it - $f_{xy}$ is just a function, and they're asking you to partially evaluate it at $y=3$. For $y=3$, $f_{xy}(x,3)=0$ since $3 > 2$.

It looks like you're attempting to do the calculations for finding the marginal pdf, but that's not what was asked for in this question.